# Двухуровневое выпадающее меню

Tags: javascript, html

Как из этого сделать двухуровневое меню?

```
<label>Адрес </label>
<select>
<option>район 1</option>
<option>район 2</option>
<option>район 3</option>
<option>район 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Собственно никак!

Answer (score 1):

`<sarcasm>`Как из списка сделать меню?`</sarcasm>`

`Если вы хотите так:
Район 1
--улица 1
--улица 2
Район 2
--улица 3
--улица 4`

То и добавляйте в текст пункта маркеры. Если вы хотите, чтобы пользователь не мог выбрать пункт "Район 1" обработайте либо событие "onChange" у select. Либо делайте 2 выпадающих списка аякс и пр плюшки.

Comment: а какие это маркеры?

Comment: Да что вы тут городите всякое.
Если человек не знает как оформить списки, а использует для этого выпадающий элемент select для формы - то писать ответы тут бесполезно.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону [optgroup](http://htmlbook.ru/html/optgroup).